# AWS Cognito - verify token using JWT vs cognito.getUser SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, amazon-cognito

I am using the following doc by AWS for verifying the incoming token with Cognito to verify the user in cognito pool:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-verifying-a-jwt.html

Now I also need to verify one of the custom attributes (email) of that user. (Basically this is to mitigate a case where some user can change their email-id in the API payload to access someone else's details).

The Cognito SDK I found to do this was this : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_GetUser.html

It works just fine, however this led me to a question :
Since I'm sending access token in this SDK, do I need to use the former jwt-based token verification as well? Because this SDK also handles the case where token is invalid/expired and sends error codes accordingly. Is there something I'm missing which the former case handles and the latter one doesn't ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no, you can ignore the contents of the JWT.

Longer answer: JWT tokens provide a fast way to verify that a user has been authenticated, without the need to check a database or external service. This can be very important in a high-volume application.

However, they have several limitations:

- A JWT token is issued with an expiration timestamp. If you rely on the JWT, you do not have a way to forcibly log-out a user until that timestamp expires.
- To be secure, your JWT token *must* be signed using an asymmetric keypair (I mention this simply because a lot of people have implemented their own identity servers incorrectly; Cognito does it right).
- The claims that are in the token (and are signed by the identity server) may not be sufficient for your needs. Best practice is to minimize the size of the token, and iirc Cognito follows this practice by only including the user attributes that are directly tied to authentication.

If any of these limitations apply to a particular use-case (and it sounds like the third applies to you), then you'll have to make that external service call to the identity server. And if you do that, *and the server reports authentication status,* then there's no need to pay attention to the token.

Comment: so am I correct to infer that generally speaking SDK call to Cognito which includes the token handles the authentication better than the custom jwt authentication ?

Comment: It's a tradeoff: if you rely on the JWT token you don't have to make a call back to Cognito (which can add 20-50 ms to your processing time), but you can't get all of the user's information. NB: it's authorization at this point; authentication already happened.

Comment: There's one part of this answer I don't understand.  If you call GetUser to get user attributes, the docs say you have to pass it an unexpired access token.  If it verifies that it's unexpired, then is it also using JWKS for me, verifying the signature?  If it's checking that the access token is unexpired it must be, but the docs don't explicitly say this.